# Flutter ListView adjustPositionForNewDimensions after orientation change

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, orientation

I am currently implementing a ListView that tries to keep the current "selected" item in the middle of the ListView.

This is achieved simply by implementing a custom ScrollPhysics that looks familiar to the [PageScrollPhysics](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/37b72342b0ce86fbfc238a9d43e524608b89af3a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart#L535)

However if the orientation of the screen changes (and thus the dimensions of the ListView) the item in the middle isn't correct anymore. I noticed there is a method that we can overwrite in the ScrollPhysics called [adjustPositionForNewDimensions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eefbe85c8bd4185a087cd83251e552be326568ad/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_physics.dart#L345) which works perfectly if the dimensions of the ListView changes programatically but somehow this method doesn't get triggered if the orientation changes.

This method should get called from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/37b72342b0ce86fbfc238a9d43e524608b89af3a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart#L590) which in turn gets called [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/37b72342b0ce86fbfc238a9d43e524608b89af3a/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart#L550). But somehow on the ListView its dimensions change the variable `haveDimensions` is true but after an orientation change (and thus dimension change) its `false` resulting in skipping the `correctForNewDimensions` check.

It's not completly clear to me why this variable is `false` even though the dimensions did change. Am I missing something, or should this behavior be implemented in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to change some values on orientation change then it is pretty easy with flutter, you can use an `OrientationBuilder` which can detect when the orientation of the current device is being changed and update your code accordingly :

```
body: OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
),
```

You can find more about it on : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation